# What is the reason of this error? How do I solve this?

Tags: angular, typescript, typeerror

I want to push that **'obj'** variable of type **'Uni.model.ts'**   inside  **'universitiesListFromDB'**
which is just an array of the same type.

```
for (let i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {
  var matchedFlag: Boolean = false;
  if (this.universitiesListFromDB.length <= 0) {
    for (
      let j = 0;
      j < this.universitiesListFromDB.length && !matchedFlag;
      j++
    ) {
      if (
        this.universitiesListFromDB[j].uniName ==
        responseData[i].UniversityNameOfUser
      ) {
        matchedFlag = true;
      }
    }
    if (matchedFlag == false) {
      var obj: Uni;
      obj.uniName = responseData[i].UniversityNameOfUser;    <<----ERROR HERE
      this.universitiesListFromDB.push(obj);
    }
    //check MatchedFlag, if false then assign
  } else {
    this.universitiesListFromDB[0].uniName =
      responseData[i].UniversityNameOfUser;
  }
}
```

The Error:

```
core.js:6006 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'uniName' of undefined
at HomepageService.initiallizeRemainings (homepage.service.ts:86)
at SafeSubscriber._next (homepage.service.ts:55)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33)
at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
```

Following is the array i want **'obj'** to be pushed in but having trouble to do so. Can somebody guide?

```
universitiesListFromDB: Uni[] = []
```

The array is of type Uni.model.ts same as the variable 'obj'

```
export interface Uni {
uniName: String;
}
```

Comment: Please do not ask questions as links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only declare `obj`, but you don't initialize it.

Change

```
var obj: Uni;
obj.uniName = responseData[i].UniversityNameOfUser;
```

to

```
let obj: Uni = { uniName: responseData[i].UniversityNameOfUser };
```

Note:
Avoid using `var`. Use `const` (immutable) or `let` (mutable) instead.